# SSRS 2012, produce 2 dataset from single sp with single run

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

is this possible, I have report with details page and then I need total by Account by parameterized period which makes it very complicated to do in RDL ( this is 100% out of questions).
I'm thinking to.

```
1. Run sp, where details part stored  in table  trade_details (and  truncated before)
2. on  the same run  same sp produces  output for trade summary.
3. in RDL I can use simple select with text for details 

Select * from trade_details

4.  for Summary I will have output from sp.
```

Problem is timing: select * from #3 need to be synced, wait till sp is done, as parameter/data is different each time, not sure if this possible to make any switch/check to see if sp run is completed let say 10 sec ago otherwise go sleep for 10 seconds.

Tx

Comment: It's better to somehow format and fetch all of the data in a single run.

Comment: Why is it have to be in same SP? Also can you provide the script so we can look at it and provide feedback than just the story?

Comment: @Viking Thanks all, it's really impossible to format detail and summary data in one dataset, it's counted by dynamic period coming from parameter, etc. For clarity of this post let's don't go this direction.

Comment: @Curious I just want  to run sp single time as a main load comes to processing details, but I can run it 2 times for each dataset, this what I have now, not a problem.   I just want to learn if any tricky  things available in SSRS  and make it faster.

Comment: Can you share the details of code and what you are doing now when it comes to get the details and Summary separate so we can provide inputs on if it is possible to make in in one run?

Comment: #Curious, Tx, it's OK, I don't want to put details re this datasets, you can twist this and make it work, but it's out of scope of my main question.  I just want to see if other solution exists how to produce 2 datasets out from single sp, like I posted at the end of my post.